# How to add button on camera Preview Frame in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-camera

I simply dragged and dropped the button on Camera Preview Frame but the button is not visible when I execute the app on the device, I do not see the button. Please help to resolve this issue. I wan to add a Flash button on the camera preview. Here is the XML code.

```
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1.05" >

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/button1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/flash_button" />

  </FrameLayout>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:text="@string/capture_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`.

Here's the working XML that I'm using:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ind" >
</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_switchcam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_switch_button"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_capture_button"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```